# Where can I change the e-mail address my notifications are sent to?

Tags: support, email-notification

I managed to change my login e-mail address some months ago. But still my notifications (from do-not-reply@stackexchange.com) are sent to the old address (I initially signed up with this address at StackExchange about 4 years ago). Where can I change the e-mail address notifications are sent to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change it at https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current

This is the email address where all  notifications are sent to.